# Erlang syntax for nested function with if

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, anonymous-function

I've been looking around and can't find examples of this and all of my syntax wrestling skills are failing me. Can someone please tell me how to make this compile?? My ,s ;s or .s are just wrong I guess for defining a nested function...

I'm aware there is a function for doing string replaces already so I don't need to implement this, but I'm playing with Erlang trying to pick it up so I'm hand spinning some of the basics I need to use..

```
replace(Whole,Old,New) ->
    OldLen = length(Old),
    ReplaceInit = fun(Next, NewWhole) ->
              if
                  lists:prefix(Old, [Next|NewWhole]) -> {_,Rest} = lists:split(OldLen-1, NewWhole), New ++ Rest;
                  true -> [Next|NewWhole]
              end,
    lists:foldr(ReplaceInit, [], Whole).
```

Basically I'm trying to write this haskell (also probably bad but beyond the point):

```
repl xs ys zs =
  foldr replaceInit [] xs
  where
    ylen = length ys
    replaceInit y newxs
      | take ylen (y:newxs) == ys = zs ++ drop (ylen-1) newxs
      | otherwise = y:newxs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is that in an `if` you are only allowed to use *guards* as tests. Guards are very restricted and, amongst other things, calls to general Erlang functions are not allowed. Irrespective of whether they are part of the OTP release or written by you. The best solution for your function is to use `case` instead of `if`. For example:

```
replace(Whole,Old,New) ->
    OldLen = length(Old),
    ReplaceInit = fun (Next, NewWhole) ->
                      case lists:prefix(Old, [Next|NewWhole]) of
                          true ->
                              {_,Rest} = lists:split(OldLen-1, NewWhole),
                              New ++ Rest;
                          false -> [Next|NewWhole]
                      end
                  end,
    lists:foldr(ReplaceInit, [], Whole).
```

Because of this `if` is not used that often in Erlang. See [about `if`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76465) and [about guards](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79507) in the Erlang documentation.

Comment: well, the 'fun' end is missing also. Actually, what is the replace function is supposed to do?

Comment: I was doing a case at first but it had the identical syntax errors that the case was running into.. This gives the identical syntax error.

Comment: @user425720 the replace function should work as: replace("Hello Donut!", "Donut", "World") -> "Hello World!" the technique using a foldr that functions in this way works, it's just a matter of getting the nested function to end somehow syntactically correctly??

Comment: @user425720 Yes it was missing an `end`, now fixed.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa The syntax error you got was because of your missing `end` (like mine), but even if you had fixed that you would then have got a compiler error because of the illegal test in the `if`.

Comment: @rvirding thankyou! That's all I was missing was an extra end, I wrestled with this way too much, please mention in your answer that I'm missing an end in case anyone else see's this question because they're having the same problem.